# What is the 'criteria' epsilon and maxCount from calcOpticalFlowPyrLK

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

I don't really get what are `epsilon` and `maxCount` from `criteria` in `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`. Can someone give me more information about it ? The definition in the openCV documentation is not clear enough for me..

[Documentation `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html)

Answer (score 1):

For [`cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk), it calculates an optical flow for a sparse feature set using the **iterative Lucas-Kanade method** with pyramids.

The **`TermCriteria criteria`** (including `maxCount` and `epsilon`) is used to determine when to stop this process, particarly

- **criteria.maxCount:** this specifies the max number of the iterations it will take; the procedure will stop if it reaches this number.
- **criteria.epsilon:** this specifies the min search window it can process on; the procedure will stop when the search window moves by less than this.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand what "the procedure will stop when the search window moves by less than this" means.

Comment: @DouglasAdams "The procedure will stop" means this function will stop running, i.e. return back to whoever calls it.